# Как удалить элементы из массива с сохранением порядка остальных членов за O(n), используя O(1) памяти?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм

Задали очень "простую" задачку на интервью. Есть у кого идеи, как можно решить?

> Дан вектор интов(или массив, как угодно). Удалить из него все единицы с сохранением порядка остальных членов за **O(n)**, используя **O(1)** дополнительной памяти.

К ЯП можно не привязываться.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да проблем-то... Два указателя. Один - на текущий рассматриваемый элемент, второй - на место для его записи. Изначально они указывают на первый элемент. Дальше просто идем и смотрим - что там.

Не 1 - копируем (если указатели не совпадают), перемещаем оба указателя.

1 - перемещаем просто указатель дальше...

Вот [рабочий код](https://ideone.com/1b3Dhu):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a[30];
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) a[i] = rand()%10;


    for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) cout << a[i] << " "; cout << endl;


    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] != 1) if (i != j) a[j++] = a[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < j; ++i) cout << a[i] << " "; cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Все гениальное, как говорится... Даже стыдно стало... 
Только _if (i != j)_ , вроде, лишнее - первый элементик съедается..

Comment: Да просто нервный ступор на собеседовании... бывает...